# terminate mysqld gracefully on command line?

Tags: mysql

I started mysqld manually on the command line and it's now in the foreground. How can I terminate it gracefully? Pressing 'control \' causes it to coredump.

Answer (score 0):

You can shutdown mysqld direct from other commandline.

Write **SHUTDOWN** in the CLI from mysql or

# mysql -hxxxxx -uroot -pxxxxx -e "SHUTDOWN" from commandline

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqladmin -u root -h <IP> shutdown
```

run from commandline.